# Titanium Mobile Sockt programming

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I had Mobile project using Titanium which need Chatting functionality so i found two way to do that...like using **socket programming and by using Web services**  so which way is better and what are the Requirements for Sockets Based programming .....plz Help me.....

i had got reference for code 
https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.cloud/tree/master/commonjs/example/windows/chats

but i confuse which way i have to fellow ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dilip

If you want to implement chat application you have more option to do that.

I have already do that with socket.io that is really fine for me and also helps me a lot. And its very speedy .

And i have also experience with cloud that is also good but as per i say that socket.io is good compare to webservices.

[Socket.io In Appcelerator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10ogNjWCpyc)

Prefer this it really helps you to you to understand socket.io

[Socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Thanks,

Dharmik

Comment: Tanks a lot Dharmik i studied that one and fount very good .....and  now i am working on that ....but for that i want know about server requirements .....if u have any guideline.....plz help me ,.....thanks lot ones again ....

Comment: I follow this Url . please look this once 
[https://github.com/dharmik/socket.io-titanium](https://github.com/dharmik/socket.io-titanium)

Comment: thanks Dharmik it is very use full for me....now i am working on that....thanks...